# PHP stdClass set 'id' property odd behavior

Tags: php, stdclass

Can Anyone Explain This Behavior?

```
    $object = new stdClass();


    //This works.
    $object->test = "Test";

    //This works.
    $arbitrary = "arbitrary";
    $object->$$arbitrary = "again, testing";

    //This works.
    $object->id = "2";

    //This fails
    $test = "id";
    $object->$$test  = "2";  // On this line.
```

I'm trying to set the 'id' property through a dynamic variable name.  I can set the 'id' property fine if I explicitly state it.  I can set other variable names dynamically  - i.e 'arbitrary'.   Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no variable named `$id`.

Try this

```
$id = "2";

$test = "id";
$object->$$test  = "2";  // On this line.
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was thinking that $object->$$test would evaluate to $object->id, but instead it looks for the value in a variable named id.  I think what I was looking for was $object->{$test} to evaluate to $object->id.

Answer (score 1):

It is about how php evaluates `$object->$$test`;

First the the `$$test` is evaluated, this leads to a var `$id` and that is gives a `Notice: Undefined variable: id`

A solution would be to define a variable `$id`, but better is to use  `$object->{$test}`

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error. you want this I believe:

```
$object->{$test}
```

instead of

```
$object->$$test
```